# get height from style attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to get the height from a style attribute on a div?

```
<div style="height:100px;"></div>
```

I can't use `.height()` as this will just return me the current height of the element - I need to check if the style has been set and then get that height if it has

Comment: Isn't the `style` going to change the `height` of your element and therefor the same?

Comment: @putvande: Probably but not necessarily, a style sheet `!important` rule overrules an inline style (unless the inline style is also `!important`). Also sometimes a style value is not used by the browser. So it's *possible* that the style property and the height will be different.

Comment: @putvande I only need to change the height of a div if it has the height set in the style attribute (otherwise it will adjust itself automatically as the height will be auto)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way is to go straight to the `style` property:

```
var heightStyleValue = $("selector for your element")[0].style.height;
```

You **don't** want to use jQuery's [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function because that will give you the *calculated* height, not the value from the `style` object.

Comment: @Pete Gud response b4 the timer ends

Answer (score 0):

Use [**css()**](http://api.jquery.com/css/) in jquery

```
$('div').css('height');
```

Comment: Nope, that gives you the *calculated* height, like `height()` does.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder calculated height means?

Comment: @AnoopJoshi: You could have `style="height: 20px"` but have `css` return `40`. Why? Because of an `!important` stylesheet rule overriding the `style` value. (Or because the browser ignored the style value, as it does in some situations.)

Answer (score 0):

*I can't use .height() as this will just return me the current height of the element (...)*

How is this possible? Unless you're using some `!important` statements (which you should avoid), the style attribute has higher specificity than anything else in your CSS. Therefore, the height returned by `height()` should be the same, unless it's constrained by some other container.

However in order to achieve what you want to do, you need to do 2 things:

1. Assign an ID to your div so you can target it in your Javascript
2. Use:

   `document.getElementById("yourID").style.height;`

Comment: yes but if no style is set, I don't want the height and css('height') does the same as .height()

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use elem.style.height because the named values of style have default values.
If you actually want to know which style parameters has been set, treat style as an array.

Vanilla:

```
// get style attributes that were actually set on the element
function getStyle(elem,prop) {
    var actuallySetStyles = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < elem.style.length; i++) {
        var key = elem.style[i];
        if (prop == key)
            return elem.style[key];
        actuallySetStyles[key] = elem.style[key];
    }
    if (!prop)
        return actuallySetStyles;
}

console.log(getStyle(elem,'height'));
console.log(getStyle(elem));
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({

    // get style attributes that were set on the first element of the jQuery object
    getStyle: function (prop) {
        var elem = this[0];
        var actuallySetStyles = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < elem.style.length; i++) {
            var key = elem.style[i];
            if (prop == key)
                return elem.style[key];
            actuallySetStyles[key] = elem.style[key];
        }
        if (!prop)
            return actuallySetStyles;
    }
}


console.log(jQuery(elem).getStyle('height'));
console.log(jQuery(elem).getStyle());
```